# Roommate matching algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, matching, weighted-graph

I'm currently in an advanced data structure class and learned a good bit about the graph. For this summer, I was asked to help write an algorithm to match roommates. Now for my data structure class, I've written a City Path graph and performs some sorting and prims algorithms and I'm sort of thinking that a graph may be a great place to start with my roommate matching algorithm.

I was thinking that our data base could just be a text file, nothing too fancy. However I could initialize each nodes in the graph as a student each student would have an un-directed edge to many more students (no edge to the student who doesn't want to be roommate with another one, the sorority also doesn't want repeating roommate). Now I could also make the edge weights more, depending on the special interest.

Everything listed above is quite simple and I don't think I'll run into any problem implementing it. But here is my question:

How should I update the common interest field? Should I start that with a physical survey and then go back into the text file and update the weight of the edge manually? Or should I be creating a field that keeps track of the matching interests?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to design is called *bipartite matching*. Fortunately unlike other bipartite matching algorithms, you won't need fancy graph algorithms and complex implementation for this. This is very close of [Stable Marriage Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) and surprisingly there are very effective even easier algorithm for this.

If you are interested, I can share my C++ implementation of stable marriage problem.

Comment: @NamVu sure. Here you go https://github.com/kaidul/Data_Structure_and_Algorithms_Library/blob/master/algorithms/stable_marriage_problem.cpp

Comment: @NamVu The comments on the code is quite uncensored :p Ignore the comments

Comment: noted as per https://github.com/kaidul/Data_Structure_and_Algorithms_Library/blob/master/algorithms/stable_marriage_problem.cpp#L1 :)